# How to get ip address from sock structure in c?

Tags: c, sockets, ip-address

I'm writing simple server/client and trying to get client IP address and save it on server side to decide which client should get into critical section. I googled it several times but couldn't find proper way to get IP address from sock structure.

I believe this is a way to get IP from sock struct after server accept request from client. More specifically in c after server execute

```
csock = accept(ssock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &clen)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 61, accepted):

OK assuming you are using IPV4 then do the following:

```
struct sockaddr_in* pV4Addr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&client_addr;
struct in_addr ipAddr = pV4Addr->sin_addr;
```

If you then want the ip address as a string then do the following:

```
char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop( AF_INET, &ipAddr, str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN );
```

IPV6 is pretty easy as well ...

```
struct sockaddr_in6* pV6Addr = (struct sockaddr_in6*)&client_addr;
struct in6_addr ipAddr       = pV6Addr->sin6_addr;
```

and getting a string is almost identical to IPV4

```
char str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop( AF_INET6, &ipAddr, str, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN );
```

Comment: You forgot to pass the `str` buffer to `inet_ntop()`. And `sin_addr` is a struct - one has to use `sin_addr.s_addr`. Worth noting that IPv4 address is stored in network byte order and to see it as a hex number one would need to use `ntohl(pV4Addr->sin_addr.s_addr)`.

Comment: Points taken ... you also missed my not using a lowercase "in6_addr" ;) On the ntohl front I don't often bother as I can still do equality checks (provided both are in network order) and it would break the inet_ntop (wouldn't it?).

Comment: This question is tagged C - you can't leave out the `struct` in types like `struct sockaddr_in *`.  Also, the IPV4 method should use `struct in_addr` instead of `int` to store addresses, analagous to the IPV6 method you show.

Answer (score 46):

The easier and correct way for extracting IP address and port number would be:

```
printf("IP address is: %s\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));
printf("port is: %d\n", (int) ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
```

The SoapBox's accepted answer won't be correct for all architectures. See [Big and Little Endian](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html).

Answer (score 27):

Assuming `client_addr` is a `struct sockaddr_in` (which it usually is).  You can get the IP address (as a 32-bit unsigned integer) from `client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr`.

You can convert it to a string this way:

```
printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n",
  int(client.sin_addr.s_addr&0xFF),
  int((client.sin_addr.s_addr&0xFF00)>>8),
  int((client.sin_addr.s_addr&0xFF0000)>>16),
  int((client.sin_addr.s_addr&0xFF000000)>>24));
```

Comment: You should use inet_ntoa() instead of fiddling with the bits manually.

Comment: `inet_ntoa` is not thread-safe, although that might not be important for most cases where it's used. A safe alternative is `inet_ntop`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nice and simple. I like it.