# Linux UDP in kernel space get sockaddr_in

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I use UDP in kernel space. When some packet is incoming, I store it on `workqueue_struct` and then I process it.
Everything working. Now I would like send answer to client. So, I need IPv4 address from `struct sock`.

I found out function `kernel_getsockname()` but this function not return `sockaddr_in` which I need to `sock_sendmsg()`.

My question is: How can I get `sockaddr_in` from `struct sock`?

Comment: Unless your UDP socket is connected, you cannot get the `sockaddr_in` from the `sock`, because the `sockaddr_in` is tied to the packet, not the socket. Add some details about what you have (structs) about the packets.

Comment: Thank for reply. I would like send answer to the host which send me message. (( I use this part of code: https://github.com/joninvski/iptables_dev_examples/blob/master/udpFilter/udpRecvCallback.c ))

Answer (score 0):

The client address is in is a struct sockaddr_in then you can get the ip address from client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr.                                                   It will be a 32 bit unsigned integer.

for eg.

struct sockaddr_in* clientAddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&client_addr;
int ip = clientAddr->sin_addr.s_addr;

Comment: Ok thank, but when I can get client_addr ? I have only pointer to struct sock (callback function struct socket->sk->sk_data_ready ) . Is there some function to get client_addr from sock??

Comment: i think you can get using csock = accept(ssock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &clen)

Comment: I'm sorry but I still do not get it.... I use this pease of code: https://github.com/joninvski/iptables_dev_examples/blob/master/udpFilter/udpRecvCallback.c
Now i need to change address on line 48 (to.sin_addr.s_addr = in_aton("127.0.0.1"); )

Comment: pl. check if the below discussion in stack overflow can be of helphttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060950/how-to-get-ip-address-from-sock-structure-in-c

Answer (score 0):

According to linux kernel documentation, (https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/networking/API-struct-sock.html) struct sock has a member named `sk_rcv_saddr` which can be equated to `struct cnic_sockaddr *saddr`

`cnic_sockaddr` has local and remote sockaddr_in structure members and you can get ip address from it. For exemple, Im not sure, but...

```
struct cnic_sockaddr saddr = sk.sk_rcv_saddr;
```

where sk is sock structure variable.
so your sockaddr_in is

```
saddr.remote.v4
```

and you can parse it like that:

```
char* parse_sinaddr(const struct in_addr saddr)
{ 
    static char ip_str[16];
    bzero(ip_str, sizeof(ip_str));
    int printed_bytes = 0;

    printed_bytes = snprintf(ip_str, sizeof(ip_str), "%d.%d.%d.%d", 
        (saddr.s_addr&0xFF), 
        ((saddr.s_addr&0xFF00)>>8), 
        ((saddr.s_addr&0xFF0000)>>16), 
        ((saddr.s_addr&0xFF000000)>>24));

    if (printed_bytes > sizeof(ip_str)) return NULL;

    return ip_str;
}


char *ip_str = parse_sinaddr(saddr.remote.v4.sin_addr.in_addr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the source IP from the received packet because an UDP socket in itself doesn't contain the remote end point (because UDP is 1-to-many).

Your packet is essentially contained in the `sk_buff`. You could try do do that to get the remote IP :

```
struct iphdr *ip_header = ip_hdr(skb);
to.sin_addr.s_addr = ip_header->saddr;
```

`ip_hdr()` is in `linux/ip.h`.

Comment: Work perfectly! Thank